# Error while passing vector<string> to instance of object in main

Tags: c++, c++11

```
vector<string> hj{ "jack" };
vector<double> x{ 8 };
NamePairs pair1(hj,x);
```

This is the only way the code runs. Is there a way to pass the values directly to pair1 object instance

Comment: Please, please do take the time to copy and paste your code, and ask an actual question here.

Comment: Your `NamePairs` constructor waits `vector` arguments, but you provide `char` array and `float`. I do not understand why you expect vectors in your constructor signature.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: rems4e the code is in the pictures

Comment: @M.H You shouldn't post pictures of text, you should post text. If you don't know how to copy and paste text, go to the library and check out an "Introduction to computers"-style book.

Comment: Apparently when I define both vector string and double as variables the program compiles, why can't I just pass the values directly to the object pair1

Comment: Will you please edit the question and post the actual code and your question there? Not everyone has the patience to read all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong *types* to your constructor:
`"Jack"` is of type `const char[5]` and the second argument `28.2` is of type `double`
Your constructor though is expecting a `std::vector<string>` and a `std::vector<double>`. So the problem is your constructor is expecting a "list" of strings and doubles, what you are not giving him.
Considering the name of your class the correct solution should be:

```
class NamePairs
{
private:
    double age;
    std::string name;
public:
    NamePairs(const std::string& name, double Age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
};
```

Now you can instantiate it like that:

```
NamePairs pair("Alfred", 43.4);
```

Also consider using a [`std::pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/)

---

Considering you want a list of Persons that each have a Name and Age there a some different Solutions:
You could create a class `Person` that has two attributes:

```
class Person
{
private:
    double Age;
    std::string Name;
public:
    Person(double age, const std::string& name)
    {
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
    }
};
```

And use it like that:

```
std::vector<Person> persons;
persons.push_back(Person(23.4, "Alfons");
```

Or you also could (more like your try) create a class PersonList like this:

```
class PersonList
{
private:
    std::vector<double> Ages;
    std::vector<std::string> names;
public:
    void addPerson(double Age, const std::string& Name)
    {
        Ages.push_back(Age);
        Names.push_back(Names);
    }
};
```

And use it like that:

```
PersonList list;
list.addPerson(23.5, "Andrea");
```

*I would greatly prefer the first Approach because it is way easier to handle the Persons if they're are not in the list(e.g. returned by a accessor or passed around to other functions/objects or if you Need to operate upon them). And it Looks way cleaner to me*

Comment: is there a way to pass a std::vector<string> and the constructor will save it name[0]

Comment: Do you want a list of names related to a list of the equivalent ages? Or what do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: `"Jack"` actually has the type `const char[5]`.

Comment: @sro5h yes, I wrote a function to add names and ages, but I need an option to pass them directly when instantiating an object without declaring any variables

Comment: So you want a class "Person" that holds a name and age, and a list of those persons? And you want to create each Person like that: `Person p("Arnulf", 45);`?

Comment: @sro5hI want a class "Person" that holds a vector of names and ages. But I want an option to enter one name,age  in the vector as Person p("Arnulf", 45);

Comment: Ok ill edit my answer, I hope I understood what you mean ;)